# Routing where one of parameter values is part of URL path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I am confused with routing in Asp.Net core 1 and I need help.
In startup.cs I have this configuration

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");      
});
```

I have created a controller 'Entities' and a method 'Get'

```
[Authorize]
public class EntitiesController : Controller
{                    
    [Produces("text/html")]
    public string Get(string entity, string type)
    {            
        return "<html><body>test</body></html>";
    }

}
```

So, when I text in url link like below works

```
http://localhost:12895/Entities/Get?entity=entity&type=type
```

and function called with params.

But I want to change this url and keep same functionality.
I want my url become

```
http://localhost:12895/Entities/entity?type=type
```

so, only `type` will be parameter and the name of `entity` will change for example

```
http://localhost:12895/Entities/human?type=type

http://localhost:12895/Entities/dog?type=type
```

but invoke the same function.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing) full info about .net core routings.

Yes. It is possible. Add an additional route in `app.UseMvc` for your class.

It should looks like a

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );      


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "entities",
        template: "Entities/{entity}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Entities", action = "Get"}
    );
});
```

Comment: Order of routes is also important as first match wins. default route would also match the entities route so you need to put the entities route before the default route as it is more specific and not as general as default route

Comment: ok works that is that i want. but in my code i have this if condition             if (entity == null)
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Entity with name {0} is unspecified", entity)); now how can now name of entity?

Comment: i found 'template: "Entities/{entity}", ' ok ty dude